# Unwanted back slashes before quotation marks while working with PDO and MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, pdo, backslash, html, quotations

I have a CMS that its administrator must use it to insert some website gadgets written in JavaScript to its database MySQL. I've used PDO for this, but it puts back slashes before all quotation marks (When I run the project on the internet). So codes appear like this in the source:

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"something.js\"></script>
```

Therefore, nothing will be shown in the page. Wheras this back slashes don't be applied when I test the application locally, and I'm able to see these gadgets in the page.
Actually, I have same codes that acts in different manners on different locations (Local and Remote). What's the problem?

This is my code:

```
try
{
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dbdirectory", $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$title = $_POST['title'];
$code = $_POST['code'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_services (title,code) VALUES (?,?)";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title,$code));
```

Comment: How do you avoid what? What do you want to avoid?
Don't put the back slashes?

Comment: Yes, I would like to prevent back slashes before quotation marks

Comment: PDO, if used correctly, will only escape data as needed to insert it into the database. The escape characters will not be included in the stored data. You are probably double escaping it somewhere, but you haven't provided any of your PHP code, so we can't tell where.

Comment: You're likely a victim of [**magic quotes**](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Comment: @deceze can I stop it while my script is running?

Comment: It's all right there in the linked manual article.